# Getting a reference of an already running session of ArcMap with ArcObjects/C#

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#

I'm new to both C# and ArcObjects and I want to get the layers on a currently opened document, which I've done via:

```
IApplication app = ???;
IMxDocument doc = (IMxDocument) app.Document;
IEnumLayer layers = doc.FocusMap.Layers;
```

I have figured out how to get IApplication app if the program opens ArcMap itself[1] or if it's an ArcMap AddIn[2].

I've been trying to figure out how to reference an already running ArcMap document with a stand alone program but have come up empty handed. Is this possible?

[1] https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/56eba175-54c1-46b4-801a-fc968e582581.htm
[2] IApplication app = ArcMap.Application;

Comment: See if my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227403/how-to-correctly-reference-arcmap-in-a-class-library/227428#227428) is helpful.